# How to determine what caused directory url to get access denied?

Tags: apache2

Using Apache 2.4.10 on two different Linux hosts.
The server configurations are very similar, and running very similar php web applications.

With one server, the uri `/uploads` produces:

```
Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
```

With the other server, that uri produces a listing of the files in the `uploads` directory below the document root.

On both servers I've done

`grep -i Indexes`

in all of the `.conf` and `.htaccess` files on both servers, and all I find is:

`Options FollowSymLinks Indexes`

There is no index.html file in that directory, though it is readable to the httpd process. What else could cause this difference? Is there a way to verify what Options settings are in effect for httpd, or show what changes them? Or other ideas for figuring out what's going on?

Comment: Does this question on StackOverflow answer your question?  [Error message “Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873295/error-message-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server)   It talks about directory indexes, deny allow directives, require directives, and file permissions.

Comment: Check the owner, group, and permissions of your folder. Keep in mind that Apache has to be able to read the directory. Depending upon the install, that can be one of several user names. However, `root` access is often required even if Apache is sand-boxed. Also, check the conf files or .htaccess file to ensure that `options indexes` is enabled. It is also possible that the files are uploaded using another user name and permissions that Apache has no access to. Cheers!!

Comment: What happens when you request `/uploads/` (ie. with a trailing slash)? If you do (temporarily) put an `index.html` file in that directory (assuming that is a defined `DirectoryIndex`), is it served? Have you tried it with another "test" directory?

Comment: Thanks for helpful comments, but @Stephen Ostermiller: the reference is about access to "/" - if that were the problem, I couldn't see anything. I can access files within the uploads directory, but giving the url for the directory itself gives a listing on one server, and access denied on the other.

Comment: @closetnoc I did check those things, and in fact I can access files within the directory, which is 775. And as I said in the original post, I ran "grep -i Indexes" on all of the conf files and .htaccess. I also grepped for Options.

Comment: @w3dk: On both servers, when I enter the request without a trailing slash, the browser adds the slash for me when it displays either the listing or error depending on server.

Comment: @w3dk: I did try putting a index.php file in the directory, and it got served properly. So it would seem that permissions are fine and somehow "Options Indexes" is turned on for one server and off for the other, which was my initial suspicion. But I'm damned if I can see why that would be the case based on looking at the minor differences between the *.conf and .htaccess files. I was hoping for some kind of trace or debug output from httpd in reading the files. BTW, I want to deny access on the server that gives listing, not the other way around :-)

Comment: Still, check the owner and group of the files. Permissions are the last thing in the list, user, group, and then permissions. Often people start with permissions. The thing is, Apache has to have access to the files. because you can see them does not Apache can. As well, check the directory itself and even going up the hierarchy to the root / where one error can stop Apache. Root or su or sudo should be able to access anything. If you are using these, you will be able to access almost anything. Make double-sure that both configurations are identical in every way. Copy files if necessary.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403 You canl also check your error logs for details. Often, there are solid clues in the error log. You can up the log level if needed. Cheers!!

Comment: What's the state of `AllowOverride` and `AllowOverrideList` (in the server config / VirtualHost / `<Directory>`)? Although this only influences whether `Options Indexes` will work in `.htaccess`. It should still be possible to set this in the server config. "BTW, I want to deny access on the server that gives listing, not the other way around :-)" - Well, in that case you just need `Options -Indexes` on the other server... ideally in the server config, but `.htaccess` would do.

Comment: @closenoc: Permissions and owner/group are fine (though since the permissions are 775 for the directory, the actual owner/group don't really matter), But I hadn't thought to check the error log. It shows: "Cannot serve directory /opt/lampp/htdocs/WWW/public/uploads/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.html.var,index.php,index.php3,index.php4) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive". So that's interesting/expected for the access denied case, but doesn't help figure out why the other server with similar config directives gives a directory listing.

Comment: I'm now wondering if I'm being bitten by the "no merging of Options unless +/- is always used" behavior. Both servers specify the Options directive without a + or - on any operands, though I still can't find anything that specifies Options Indexes in a place that *ought* to apply to the directory that is displaying a listing. I think I should explicitly specify "Options None" for "/", and then make sure that every other appearance of "Options" specifies a "+" or "-" on every operand. That really ought to fix things, though it won't tell me what was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In poring over the config files again, I see that both servers have identical `httpd.conf` files, but they include different files from the `"extra"` subdirectory to define the `vhosts`. (I'm based on `XAMPP for Linux 1.8.2-6`, which has `httpd.conf` in `/opt/lampp/etc/` and a directory `/opt/lampp/etc/extra/` containing various other conf files, including `vhosts.conf`).

The common `httpd.conf` file has `DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs"` and it contains roughly this near the top:

`<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
<Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>`

On the server that gives a directory listing, the `vhosts.conf` file contains no `Options` directives at all. So it makes perfect sense that the `Options` directive from `httpd.conf` effectively enables Indexes.

On the server that gives the `Access Denied` error, the `vhosts.conf` file contains these directives:

`<Directory /opt/lampp/htdocs>
    AllowOverride None
    Options       FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
<Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp">
    AllowOverride All
    Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
</Directory>
<Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs/test">
    AllowOverride All
    Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
</Directory>
<Directory "/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin">
    AllowOverride All
    Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
</Directory>`

I **think** what's happening is that because none of the `Options` directives contain "+" or "-" prefixes on their attributes, the `Options FollowSymLinks` directive in the first directory section of this file has the effect of cancelling all the other attributes (including `Indexes`) from the first `Options` directive in the `httpd.conf` file!

And in fact I just "proved" it by editing the `vhosts.conf` file on the server that gave the directory listing, to add:

```
<Directory /opt/lampp/htdocs>
    Options       FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
```

That one change (and running `lampp reloadapache`) caused that server also to give the access denied error, just like the other server.

Although I could leave things this way, I think I'll change all three configuration files to start out with `Options None` for "/" and `Options +FollowSymLinks +Indexes +ExecCGI +Includes` for "/opt/lampp/htdocs" in the `httpd.conf` file. And in the `vhosts.conf` files I'll put:

`<Directory /opt/lampp/htdocs>
    Options       +FollowSymLinks -Indexes -ExecCGI -Includes
</Directory>`

Comment: Where is the `/uploads` dir located? Providing it is a physical subdir of either `.../xampp` or `.../test` then `Indexes` should be enabled, since `Options FollowSymLinks Indexes` (defined in the more specific `<Directory>` container) should completely override `Options FollowSymLinks` (defined in the parent) - it shouldn't have anything to do with `+` or `-` prefixes in this instance. (Note that you do appear to need `FollowSymLinks` as well in order to enable directory indexes.) So, unless `/uploads` is located elsewhere, I think the _jury is still out_ on what is really going on here. (?)

Comment: @w3dk: It's `/opt/lampp/htdocs/WWW/public/uploads/`, where the virtual host in question has `DocumentRoot /opt/lampp/htdocs/WWW/public`. The first `Options` directive, in `httpd.conf`, is for `/opt/lampp/htdocs`, so it's not a more specific container, but the same container. I didn't expect the second directive to remove the options that were specified on the first directive for that container that were not repeated on the second one, but I guess that's what "not merged" means in the documentation. So I think the case is closed. Sorry that I didn't give the full directory tree.

Comment: Yes, in that case, a request for your `/uploads` directory is only matched by the first `<Directory /opt/lampp/htdocs>` container, which _resets_ the `Options` to  `FollowSymLinks` only (essentially removing `Indexes`, `ExecCGI`, and `Includes` set earlier in the server config) thus removing the directory index capability. The `AllowOverride None` directive would also prevent any `.htaccess` file from re-enabling it.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I'm marking this the accepted answer. And once again I apologize for not laying out the directory structure completely. I had sort of assumed that saying I was based on XAMPP implied that the document root of each virtual host was `/opt/lampp/htdocs/virthost/public`, so that the uri `/uploads` would be below that - but I now realize that's not necessarily the case at all, it is just a convention I've always used since building a Zend Framework MVC application. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Actually, the thing that threw us initially was that you stated: "...all I find is: `Options FollowSymLinks Indexes`" - if that was the case then `Indexes` should have been enabled regardless of your directory structure. Yes, you can't _assume_ anything about the directory structure. In fact, `/opt/lampp/htdocs/virthost/public` is arguably not the recommended location for your virtual hosts since you are essentially creating websites within the parent (XAMPP example) website and inheriting the config associated with that which must now be explicitly overridden - unless the sites are related.

Comment: Yes, I see, it confused me too!  I didn't appreciate that without a "+" or "-" on each attribute in an `Options` directive, the directive resets every attribute not listed, I stupidly assumed that since I had initially set `Indexes`, I should find something that explicitly unset it. The perhaps unorthodox structure is a result of my initial struggles 6 years ago setting up a sample Zend Framework application under XAMPP - after a few years, it seemed intuitive, and the way that anyone would do it :-) There are 6 closely-related ZF application sites configured as vhosts.